# Signatures on the infinite symmetric group

Tags: gr.group-theory

I have a question about the symmetric group.  Taking signatures of permutations defines a surjective homomorphism $S_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2$.  This is compatible with the natural inclusions $S_n \hookrightarrow S_{n+1}$, so we get a surjection $S_{\infty} \rightarrow \mathbb{z}/2$.  Here $S_{\infty}$ is the direct limit of the $S_n$.  In other words, $S_{\infty}$ is the group of finitely supported permutations of a countable set.

This brings me to my question.  let $S_{\infty}'$ be the set of all permutations of a countable set.  We have an inclusion $S_{\infty} \hookrightarrow S_{\infty}'$.  Does the signature map $S_{\infty} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2$ extend to $S_{\infty}'$?

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12291/sign-of-infinite-permutations. this question actually starts with this observation here and tries to replace Z/2 by another group.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer to the question is "no".  In fact, $S'_{\infty}$ is a perfect group, so there are no maps from it to an abelian group.  Even more is true -- every element of $S'_{\infty}$ can be expressed as a commutator!  This is much stronger than simply saying that $[S'_{\infty},S'_{\infty}] = S'_{\infty}$.

For these results, see Theorem 6 of the following paper.

MR0040298 (12,671e) 
Ore, Oystein
Some remarks on commutators. 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 2, (1951). 307–314.

Comment: For EVEN MORE, see the paper of M. Droste and I. Rivin (on arxiv.org, though it has now appeared online in Bulletin of the AMS).

Comment: Sorry, that's bulletin of the LMS above.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a direct way to see the answer is 'no'.

Let our countable set be the set of all integers $\mathbb{Z}$.

What is the sign of $(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)(7,8)\dots$? (Note that we're fixing all nonpositive integers here.)

Whatever it is, you can multiply by the transposition $(1,2)$ to get a permutation with the opposite sign, then you can conjugate, which doesn't affect the sign, by $(\dots,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\dots)^{-2}$ giving back the element you started with. Contradiction.

Comment: Another way to look at it: the above argument expresses $(1,2)$ as a commutator.