# Defining parity on the set of all bijections of ${\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let  $\phi:{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow {\mathbb{N}}$ be a bijection. Can we extend the notion of parity (of a finite permutation) to $\phi$ ?

In other words, Can we define a group homomorphism $\Lambda $, between the  group of all bijections of $\mathbb{N}$ to the group {1,-1,$\cdot$} such that $\Lambda(\psi)=-1$ if $\psi$ is a "transposition":

There exists $n_{1},n_{2}\in \mathbb{N}$, where $n_{1}\neq n_2$ and $\psi(n_{1})=n_{2} ,\psi(n_{2})=n_{1}$ and ${\psi(x)=x , \forall x \neq n_{1},n_{2} }$.

My guess is that building such a homomorphism requires some version of the axiom of choice / ultra-filters.

Comment: Your set is a group under composition.  This group has no normal subgroup of order $2$.  So in that sense, there is no extension of "parity".  (The kernel of a homomorphism is a normal subgroup.)

Comment: Thanks, I am unfamiliar with this fact. How can it be shown?

Comment: $S_\Bbb N$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: @Dozeri This post might direct you to some further information on this: [Normal subgroups of infinite symmetric group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/166358).

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: did you mean it has no normal subgroup of *index* $2$?

Comment: In my previous comment, I should have probably linked to this post, too: [Sign of infinite permutations?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/12291)

Comment: Should be "permutations of $\mathbb{N}$" (or: "bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself")

Comment: It's enough to write a transposition as a commutator. Namely, call X-element a permutation consisting of infinitely many cycles of each finite length (and no infinite cycle). Then it's quite clear that the product of any X-cycle $c$ with any transposition $t$ (or any finitely supported element) is also a X-cycle, and that all X-cycles are conjugate. Thus one can write $tc=bcb^{-1}$, so $t=[b,c]$.

Comment: @YCor why is it enough?

Comment: Of course, index 2.  Someone should combine these comments as an answer.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Ok, transpositions lie in a kernel, what then?

Comment: @ChristianRemling oh indeed. I was thinking about any non-identical homomorphism (which of course does not exist either).

Comment: @YCor Please consider adding your nice solution as an answer.

Comment: More generally a classification of all normal subgroups of the group of automorphisms of an infinite set is available: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166358/normal-subgroups-of-infinite-symmetric-group

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be easier, and equivalent, to consider $\mathbb{Z}.$ But I'll stick to $\mathbb{N}.$

Consider $\sigma=(2\ 3)(4\ 5)(6\ 7)\cdots$ (so $0$ and $1$ are fixed points) and $(0\ 1)\sigma.$ They have the same cycle type but should not have the same parity. Note that fixed points and the particular ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ should be irrelevant.

For a similar example with conjugation consider $\tau=(5\ 7)(9\ 11)(13\ 15)\cdots$ and $\tau'=(1\ 3)(5\ 7)(9\ 11)(13\ 15)\cdots$ which should again not gave the same parity. To turn $\tau$ into $\tau',$ conjugate by this product of two infinite cycles $$(\cdots 13\ 9\ 5\ 1\ 0\ 4\ 8 \cdots) (\cdots 11\ 7\ 3\ 2\ 6\ 20 \cdots).$$

Answer (score 7):

The signature homomorphism, defined on finitely supported permutations, does not extend to the group of all permutations.

To show this, it's enough to write a transposition as a commutator. Namely, call X-element a permutation consisting of infinitely many cycles of each finite length (and no infinite cycle). Then it's quite clear that the product of any X-cycle $c$ with any transposition $t$ (or any finitely supported element) is also a X-cycle, and that all X-cycles are conjugate. Thus one can write $tc=bcb^{-1}$, so $t=[b,c]$.