# Surjective group homomorphism from $\text{Sym}(X)$ onto $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory

For any non-empty set $X$ let $\text{Sym}(X)$ denote the group of bijections $f:X\to X$ with composition.

Is there an infinite set $X$ and a surjective group homomorphism $\pi: \text{Sym}(X)\to \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: No. Vitali proved in 1915 that every element of $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$, for $X$ infinite, is a product of squares, and therefore $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Sym}(X),\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})=\{0\}$

Comment: Or see [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846209/) for example.

Comment: (I should say that precisely Vitali stated and proved that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Sym}(X),\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})=0$, and that his method consists in proving that every element is a product of, say 4, squares.)

Comment: Just a side remark: the definition of $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ works just fine for empty $X$!  Including that unnecessary “non-empty” in so many definitions is nothing but a superstitious habit.

Comment: The answer is: no. You do not need to know anything fancy, only that every element in $Sym(X)$ is conjugate to its inverse -- which is obvious from looking at the cycle decomposition. What is less trivial is Vitali's theorem, but that is not needed to exclude existence homomorphisms to $Z$.

Comment: Nice, it's indeed even simpler than Vitali's (which is not fancy however, but takes a few more lines). Vitali's paper (which is 2-3 pages) was up to my knowledge, the first where the the group of all permutations of an infinite set was defined and considered as a group. The question of looking at homomorphisms to $Z/2Z$ was natural since the initial question was whether one can extend the signature homomorphism.

Comment: Andreas' argument also shows that it has no nontrivial homomorphism into any torsion-free abelian group (while Vitali's fact does not discard homomorphisms into $\mathbf{Q}$). Actually it shows that the abelianization has exponent $\le 2$. So the combination of the two arguments shows that the group is perfect, which of course follows from Onofri's later (and more difficult) classification of normal subgroups.

Comment: Okay to close the question as "no longer relevant". But... is it *really* so offtopic?

Comment: It also has many sort-of duplicates: one already mentioned https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846209/; it is already answered in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12291/ (although the question is distinct), etc (search "Schreier-Ulam")

Comment: More explicitly, it's a sub-duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281289/defining-parity-on-the-set-of-all-bijections-of-mathbbn

Comment: @Qfwfq: This is a question which can be answered by any competent google search and thus is not of research level. We see a lot of questions asked for the sake of asking (I believe) and this should be discouraged in my opinion.

Comment: @YCor, what is the Vitali paper?

Comment: @LSpice G. Vitali. Sostituzioni sopra una infinità numerabile di elementi. Bollettino Mathesis 7: 29–31, 1915.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer here is negative. In fact, any non-trivial quotient group of the symmetric group $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ contains a copy of $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$. Indeed, by the [Baer-Schreier-Ulam Theorem](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Baer-Schreier-Ulam_theorem), 
any normal subgroup $N\ne \mathrm{Sym}(X)$ is contained in the subgroup $\mathrm{Sym}_<(X)$ of permutations having support of cardinality $<\kappa:=|X|$. Let $q:\mathrm{Sym}(X)\to \mathrm{Sym}(X)/N$ be the quotient homomorphism.

Since $X$ is infinite, we can choose a family of pairwise distinct $\{x_{p}\}_{p\in \kappa\times\kappa}$ in $X$.

For every permutation $\pi\in \mathrm{Sym}(\kappa)$ of $\kappa$ define the permutation $\bar\pi\in \mathrm{Sym}(X)$ letting $\bar\pi(x_{\alpha,\beta})=x_{(\pi(\alpha),\beta)}$ for $(\alpha,\beta)\in \kappa\times \kappa$ and $\bar\pi(x)=x$ for any $x\in X\setminus\{x_{p}:p\in \kappa^2\}$. It is clear that $e:\mathrm{Sym}(\kappa)\to \mathrm{Sym}(X)$, $e:\pi\mapsto\bar\pi$ is a group homomorphism whose image $e(\mathrm{Sym}(\kappa))$ in $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ is disjoint with the subgroup $\mathrm{Sym}_{<}(X)\supset N$ and hence the composition $q\circ e:\mathrm{Sym}(\kappa)\to \mathrm{Sym}(X)/N$ is injective.

Comment: It would be nice if you could use a consistent notation for the symetric group over a set.

Comment: @LucGuyot Done! Thank you for your comment.